# Finding IP address of another computer on LAN in python

Tags: python, network-programming, ip-address

I'm trying to use socket to exchange data between two computers in Python. Right now, I'm able to connect the computer together but I have to manually go in the code and specify the IP address of the other computer. However the code needs to be fully autonomous on boot. How should I do that? Is there a way in python to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Use the hostname instead **or** lookup the ip address based on the hostname?

Comment: I guess that computers are connected using the Internet connection. Does at least one computer have a permanent IP address? Can both computers be restarted simultaneously (specifically, can both IP addresses be changed simultaneously)?

Comment: Use a reverse connection to your ip.

Comment: Both computers are on a public network (university network) and none of them can have a permanent IP address. Both computers will restart and I cannot interact with them. Do the computers need to be running web servers to have a hostname? If not, how can I use it?